EV3 Freezes with STOP block inside Program: Facing an issue with EV3 bricks freezing when stopping a daisy chained program. Any tips to prevent this?
Subject: Need Help with LEGO EV3 Freezing Issue in Daisy Chain Mode
Hello fellow LEGO enthusiasts,
I am currently facing a challenge with my LEGO EV3 project. I have a complex program running across three EV3 bricks connected in daisy chain mode. Whenever I use the 'Stop' block to end the program through the software, the EV3 system freezes, requiring a hard reset to recover.
I'm looking for advice on how to properly implement a stop command in my program without causing the EV3 to freeze. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any tips on how to handle this in daisy chain setups?
I appreciate any insights or recommendations you can share!
Thank you!
I've updated the firmware to version 1.10E and tried closing all loops before using the 'Stop' block, but the issue persists. Occasionally, the system does not freeze, but in 99% of cases, it still does.
